# Fax server routing via email (Exchange 2007)

Tags: networking, email, exchange, fax

I'm trying to set up the fax server role on a Windows server 2008. All is working as expected apart from the "Route through email" incoming routing. I keep getting "Retrying Routing" followed by "Routing failed".

I've set up the server address to server.domain.local using port 25. I have tried using telnet and can send without logging in, however can log in if needed (Basic or Intergrated?)

Anything I'm missing?

Answer (score 0):

Did you follow all the instructions from this MS Guide? 
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff630162(v=ws.10).aspx#BKMK9

Quick questions:
1. Do you have the "route through email" option selected?
2. Do you have the SMTP server setting properly inputed? Try using the IP address of teh Exchange server versus a DNS name.
3. Do you have an email address specified for the incoming faxes? Can you connect to that mailbox?
4. Do you have "Fax Delivery Receipts" enabled? If so, disable just to keep things simple for now.

Obviously, your Exchange receive connector is reachable. Can you try to send an email to yourself as the FROM address you inputed in your settings using Telnet? Maybe, you are not allowed to send as that user.